# How to get last Friday?

Tags: python, datetime

The code below should return last Friday, 16:00:00. But it returns [Friday of previous week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172782/find-the-friday-of-previous-last-week-in-python). How to fix that?

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
test = (now - datetime.timedelta(days=now.weekday()) + timedelta(days=4, weeks=-1))
test = test.replace(hour=16,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)
```

Upd. I use the following approach now - is it the best one?

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if datetime.datetime.now().weekday() > 4:
    test = (now - datetime.timedelta(days=now.weekday()) + timedelta(days=4))
else:
    test = (now - datetime.timedelta(days=now.weekday()) + timedelta(days=4, weeks=-1))
test = test.replace(hour=16,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)
```

Upd2. Just to give an example. Let's assume that today is *Oct 5, 2012*. In case current time is equal to or less than *16:00* it should return *Sep 28, 2012*, otherwise - *Oct 5, 2012*.

Comment: Holy crab nuggets. Split your code up!

Comment: @LA_ How do you want it to work if the current day is Friday?

Comment: @bohney, depends on the time. If 16:00 already passed, then it should be today. Otherwise - Friday of prev week.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As in the linked question, you need to use `datetime.date` objects instead of `datetime.datetime`. To get a `datetime.datetime` in the end, you can use `datetime.datetime.combine()`:

```
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# get friday, one week ago, at 16 o'clock
last_friday = (current_time.date()
    - datetime.timedelta(days=current_time.weekday())
    + datetime.timedelta(days=4, weeks=-1))
last_friday_at_16 = datetime.datetime.combine(last_friday, datetime.time(16))

# if today is also friday, and after 16 o'clock, change to the current date
one_week = datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)
if current_time - last_friday_at_16 >= one_week:
    last_friday_at_16 += one_week
```

Comment: Looks like your code if today is Oct 6, 2012 will return Sep 28, when Oct 5 is expected.

Comment: Thanks. I have to clearly explain what I need next time... Your code on Oct 5, 2012 will always return Sep 28, 2012. But in case current time is equal to or less than 16:00 it should return Sep 28, 2012, otherwise - Oct 5, 2012.

Answer (score 46):

The [`dateutil` library](http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/relativedelta.html) is great for things like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, FR
>>> datetime.now() + relativedelta(weekday=FR(-1))
datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 28, 9, 42, 48, 156867)
```

Comment: This solution is good.  You only need to add the .replace call for the time of day.

Comment: @LA_ That's a shame - wasn't aware that GAE was a constraint

Comment: I think I can install it separately. But would prefer to do it without 3rd party libraries. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: How can I get last Friday by this code if the current day is Friday?

Comment: @Americancurl you can do min(mon-1day-relativedelta(weekday=MO(-1)), mon-relativedelta(weekday=MO(-1))

Comment: datetime.now() + relativedelta(days=-1, weekday=FR(-1)) will get you last Friday even if the current date is Friday.

Answer (score 4):

This was borrowed from Jon Clements, but is the full solution:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, FR
>>> lastFriday = datetime.now() + relativedelta(weekday=FR(-1))
>>> lastFriday.replace(hour=16,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)
datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 28, 16, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution without dependency:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_last_friday():
    now = datetime.now()
    closest_friday = now + timedelta(days=(4 - now.weekday()))
    return (closest_friday if closest_friday < now
            else closest_friday - timedelta(days=7))
```

Answer (score 1):

The principle is the same as in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686735/how-to-get-time-170000-today-or-yesterday).

Get the friday of the current week and, if we are later, subtract one week.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = now.replace(hour=16,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)
sow = (today - datetime.timedelta(days=now.weekday()))
this_friday = sow + timedelta(days=4)
if now > this_friday:
     test = this_friday
else:
     test = this_friday + timedelta(weeks=-1)
```

Comment: in this answer, I suppose that from Fr. 16:00:01 on, you want the datetime of this week.

Answer (score 0):

Could be lame but to me simplest.  Get the last day of the current month and start checking in a loop (which wouldn't cost anything since max loops before finding last friday is 7) for friday. if last day is not friday decrement and the check the day before.

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime, date

def main():
    year = datetime.today().year    
    month = datetime.today().month  
    x = calendar.monthrange(year,month)
    lastday = x[1]
    while True:
        z = calendar.weekday(year, month, lastday)
        if z != 4:
            lastday -= 1
        else:
            print(date(year,month,lastday))
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```