# How to get last Thursday date of next month and next of next month using python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get Date on Last Thursday of next month and next of next month.
Currently able to get Date of last thursday on current month.

Code:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.today()
def lastThurs_currentmonth(dt):
    currDate, currMth, currYr = dt, dt.month, dt.year
    for i in range(31):
        if currDate.month == currMth and currDate.year == currYr and currDate.weekday() == 3:
            #print('dt:'+ str(currDate))
            lastThuDate = currDate
        currDate += datetime.timedelta(1)

    return lastThuDate
lastThurs_currentmonth(dt)
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 24, 11, 2, 17, 620842)
```

Now I need to get date last Thursday for next month and next of next month.

Expected Output:

date last Thursday for next month

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 29)
```

date last Thursday for next of next month

```
datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 26)
```

Ref link:
[Get the last thursday of the current month using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975886/get-the-last-thursday-of-the-current-month-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add months less one day from the start of the current month and then subtract back to the last Thursday.  Thursdays are isoweekday 4, so it's a case of subtracting off the right number of days.  Unfortunately `timedelta` doesn't allow months, so the `dateutil` library is also needed for my solution.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def last_thrs(start_date, months):
    date_to_check = datetime.date(start_date.year, start_date.month, 1) + relativedelta(months=months+1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return date_to_check - datetime.timedelta(days = ((date_to_check.isoweekday() + 3) % 7))


dt_today = datetime.date.today()
print(last_thrs(dt_today, 1))
# 2022-12-29
```