# How to get last Friday's date with Python?

Tags: python, date, python-datetime, weekday

Is there a way to use Python to get last Friday's date and store it in a variable, regardless of which day of the week the program runs?

That is, if I run the program on Monday June 19th 2021 or Thursday June 22nd 2021, it always returns the previus Friday as a date variable: 2021-07-16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the day of the week as an int we use `datetime.datetime.today().weekday()` and to subtract days from a datetime we use `datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)` now we can make a dictionary linking the day of the week to the number of days to subtract and use that dictionary to make a subtraction:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
d = {0:3,1:4,2:5,3:6,4:0,5:1,6:2}
lastfriday = datetime.today()-timedelta(days=d[datetime.today().weekday()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686991/how-to-get-last-friday)
Here's a starting point:

```
import datetime

def get_last_friday():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    last_friday = (current_time.date()
        - datetime.timedelta(days=current_time.weekday())
        + datetime.timedelta(days=4, weeks=-1))
    return last_friday
```

Comment: You should post this as a comment so it can be flagged as a duplicate